# Spring @Transactional not creating required transaction

Tags: spring, jpa, transactional

Ok, so I've finally bowed to peer pressure and started using Spring in my web app :-)...

So I'm trying to get the transaction handling stuff to work, and I just can't seem to get it.

My Spring configuration looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <bean id="groupDao" class="mil.navy.ndms.conops.common.dao.impl.jpa.GroupDao" lazy-init="true">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ><ref bean="entityManagerFactory"/></property>
    </bean>

 <!-- enables interpretation of the @Required annotation to ensure that dependency injection actually occures -->
  <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>  

  <!-- enables interpretation of the @PersistenceUnit/@PersistenceContext annotations providing convenient
       access to EntityManagerFactory/EntityManager -->
  <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

  <!-- uses the persistence unit defined in the META-INF/persistence.xml JPA configuration file -->
  <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="CONOPS_PU" /> 
  </bean>

  <!-- transaction manager for use with a single JPA EntityManagerFactory for transactional data access
       to a single datasource -->
  <bean id="jpaTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
      <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- enables interpretation of the @Transactional annotation for declerative transaction managment
       using the specified JpaTransactionManager -->
  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="jpaTransactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>

</beans>
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

  <persistence-unit name="CONOPS_PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    ... Class mappings removed for brevity...

    <properties>

      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>

      <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="****"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="*****"/>

      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@*****:1521:*****"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>

    </properties>

  </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

The DAO method to save my domain object looks like this:

```
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    protected final T saveOrUpdate (T model)
    {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager ( );
        EntityTransaction trans = em.getTransaction ( );

        System.err.println ("Transaction isActive () == " + trans.isActive ( ));

        if (em != null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (model.getId ( ) != null)
                {
                    em.persist (model);
                    em.flush ();
                }
                else
                {
                    em.merge (model);
                    em.flush ();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                em.close ();
            }
        }

        return (model);
    }
```

So I try to save a copy of my Group object using the following code in my test case:

```
    context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(configs);
    dao = (GroupDao)context.getBean("groupDao");

    dao.saveOrUpdate (new Group ());
```

This bombs with the following exception:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:301)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:341)
    at $Proxy26.flush(Unknown Source)
    at mil.navy.ndms.conops.common.dao.impl.jpa.GenericJPADao.saveOrUpdate(GenericJPADao.java:646)
    at mil.navy.ndms.conops.common.dao.impl.jpa.GroupDao.save(GroupDao.java:641)
    at mil.navy.ndms.conops.common.dao.impl.jpa.GroupDao$$FastClassByCGLIB$$50343b9b.invoke()
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
    at mil.navy.ndms.conops.common.dao.impl.jpa.GroupDao$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7359ba58.save()
    at mil.navy.ndms.conops.common.dao.impl.jpa.GroupDaoTest.testGroupDaoSave(GroupDaoTest.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:164)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:130)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:120)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:230)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
```

In addition, I get the following warnings when Spring first starts. Since these reference the entityManagerFactory and the transactionManager, they probably have some bearing on the problem, but I've no been able to decipher them enough to know what:

```
Mar 11, 2010 12:19:27 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'entityManagerFactory' is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Mar 11, 2010 12:19:27 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'entityManagerFactory' is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Mar 11, 2010 12:19:27 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'jpaTransactionManager' is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Mar 11, 2010 12:19:27 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean '(inner bean)' is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Mar 11, 2010 12:19:27 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean '(inner bean)' is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Mar 11, 2010 12:19:27 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor' is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Mar 11, 2010 12:19:27 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor' is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Mar 11, 2010 12:19:27 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@37003700: defining beans [groupDao,org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor,org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor,entityManagerFactory,jpaTransactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor]; root of factory hierarchy
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm missing? I'm totally stumped...

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The instance of entity manager obtained from `EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()` doesn't participate in Spring-managed transactions.

The usual way to obtain an entity manager is to inject it using `@PersistenceContext`-annotated property:

```
@PersistenceContext
public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) { ... }
```

Comment: I added the @PersistenceContext to my DAO class. When I run it I get: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:155) at $Proxy27.getTransaction(Unknown Source) at mil.navy.ndms.conops.common.dao.impl.jpa.GenericJPADao.saveOrUpdate(GenericJPADao.java:634) at mil.navy.ndms.conops.common.dao.impl.jpa.GroupDao.save(GroupDao.java:645)

Comment: @Steve: You shouldn't call `getTransaction` on this `EntityManager`

Comment: That's got it. I assumed that I could at least inspect the current transaction to determine if the @Transactional annotation was creating the transaction. It was simply for debuggin purposes, so when I removed it, I got my transaction.

Thanks...

Comment: Does storing the EntityManager as a field in my DAO make the DAO no longer thread-safe? I'm currently using a single instance of my DAO to process all incoming requests.

Comment: @Steve: No, it doesn't. `EntityManager` instances created by Spring's factories (such as `LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean`) are thread-safe.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is likely caused by a combination of you annotating a protected method, and using `proxy-target-class="true"`. That's a bad mix. The transactional proxy generated by Spring will only work properly with public annotated methods, but it won't complain if they're not.

Try either making the `saveOrUpdate()` method public or, better yet, define an interface for your DAO, and remove the `proxy-target-class="true"` setting. This is the safest, most predictable technique.

Comment: The method is also `final`. It prevents use of `proxy-target-class="true"` too.

Comment: Making the method public fails the same way.

Comment: Removing the final also had no effect.

Comment: Making an interface I don't understand, I already have an interface defined for the DAO. Are you suggesting that the transactional annotation be on the interface rather then the concrete class?

Also, the savoOrUpdate method is on a base class that my GroupDao derives from. Could this be causing a problem?

Comment: @Steve: Yes, I strongly suggest that you either put the `@Transctional` on the interface method declarations, or on the methods definitions in your DAO that implement the interface.

Comment: Ok, I set the proxy-target-class to false, and added the saveOrUpdate to my interface, but I still get the same results.

Comment: In addition, this was buried in my log:

WARNING: Found unrecognized persistence provider "org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence" in place of OpenJPA provider.  This provider's properties will not be used.
WARNING: Found unrecognized persistence provider "org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence" in place of OpenJPA provider.  This provider's properties will not be used.

I'm not using OpenJPA, so I don't have a clue why its looking for it, but sounds like its ignoring the provider's properties.

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

Using JPA with Spring MVC - all of my tests and code ran fine without error - symptom was that commits would simply not save to the database no matter what I tried.

I had to add 
to my applicationContext.xml and cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar aopalliance-1.0.jar

Definitely the fix in my case. Without annotation-driven Spring will not scan for the @Transactional annotation

Comment: Besides those dependencies how your applicationContext.xml ended up?